# How could I have made this a better question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am clearly still struggling to learn the art of asking a really good question. I asked what I thought was a very good question. One where I am going to try something but I am unclear what would be going on under the hood. However, judging by the votes I seem to have asked a poor question.

Any gentle guidance for this particular slow learner would be massively appreciated.

[If I use a static method in PHP to create a connection to a database will I end up with one or many connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198072/in-php-if-i-use-a-static-method-to-create-a-connection-to-a-db-will-i-end-up-wit)

Comment: I think its pretty reasonable, but I don't know PHP. Certainly not the worst question I've ever seen.

Comment: You've been meta-effected...  On a more serious note I personally think that question is fine.

Comment: my only quibble is when code is not visible , I relaly dislike horiz. scroll

Comment: That's an easy fix @Coffee ;)

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable to me, as well (but I don't know PHP).

Comment: ...Not use PHP?

Comment: Downvote hovertext: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Or any other the downvoter chooses to apply.

Comment: @Fluffmeister General: [Affected](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Affect-and-Effect-Properly)

Comment: @PeterMortensen - not in this case: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect - it was just a play on words that he had been affected by The Meta Effect, so it was rolled into one.

Comment: Your title doesn't really explain what you're doing, "Will this code create one or many connections?" would be equally informative. (Static methods have nothing to do with database connections; it's possible to write code using static methods that creates one connection, and it's possible to write code using static methods that creates many. It's like asking "Will this car using leather seats take petrol or diesel?")

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have little knowledge of PHP, so I can't judge the question itself, but generally, downvotes on a question that is not horrible in terms of grammar (i.e., it's not impossible to understand) have to do with doing your research. @slugster's answer points out different reasons which all stem from that same reason.

For example, here are some points (emphasis mine):

> I was thinking that a static method might be the best answer but *not having any familiarity with them* ...

Well, your first step was then to learn `static` methods and familiarize yourself with them.

> ... *I am unsure* if I would be actually creating lots of connections or reusing the same one.

Did you try running your code? Surely, there are ways to understand if you are reusing the connection simply by running your code. In this particular case, run the code in a loop and see if you get increased memory consumption, or print the `$conn` reference you get back (note: I'm not a PHP programmer, so the term may be incorrect) to see if they are constant.

> Have I got the right idea about static methods and will I be reusing the same connection or making new ones?

A quick search for `PHP class static` led me to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) which says you cannot access non-`static` variables from a `static` function (which makes sense to me and is the same in C++ as well). This leads me to believe that you haven't tried the code at all.

---

It's OK to be a noob, but it's not OK to be lazy. While I know a great deal of C, I'm a noob in [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29). Even then, before asking a question on Haskell, I may spend days trying to figure it out myself. In the end, when writing a question, I make sure every question I have had are tried out. Sometimes this leads to more research while writing the question and even leads to an answer.

In a widely used language like PHP, you can be sure any question you have as a noob is already answered somewhere. It may be hard to find, but it's there. If you have researched and experimented enough, your question could easily get to tens of paragraphs and include code, tables and figures.

Again, I don't know PHP much, but my best guess is that you haven't done your research and that's why you are getting downvotes. As a final note, searching Stack Overflow for `[php] static db` quickly found me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18885421/912144) which seems to be your exact problem (also lacking `static` for declaration of `$conn`).

I'm going to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: The number of questions I have found the answer too while making sure my question is worded correctly and ready to post is surprisingly high. The rigour needed to post a useful question to this site should effectively require you to work through all the options you have tried and explore all the logic of other possibilities leading to more options to try.

Comment: @angryTurtle, exactly. And having experienced that, it makes you feel even worse when you see un-researched questions, because you know how little the asker has put effort in solving their own problem. Incidentally, this is one of the reasons I don't pay much attention to stackoverflow anymore, and our stackexchange overlords seem to be in complete denial that there is a problem.

Comment: @angryTurtle I've had that experience too. I was setting up a question with reference to previous SO postings to make sure I covered everything I could. While I was doing all that and re-reading my post and reviewing my research one last time, I came across the solution I was looking for. I guess the moral of the story is 'Do Your Homework'.

Comment: I like that this answer uses specific examples, and I agree about doing some searching and at *least* trying out code before posting. However, I must ask... is it expected to spend *days* trying to figure it out by yourself before asking, when there are experienced people out there who have helpful input? I mean, I tend to only ask questions here as a last resort after days of trying and failing, but I've always attributed that to my social anxiety. (For reference, I might have expected a "reasonable person" to ask after a few hours of good effort.) Is that how it is supposed to be?

Comment: @MysteriousWhisper I don't think there's a set amount of time you should put into researching a question. I've asked well received questions after spending a few minutes Googling  and then around an hour writing an MCVE. Others, I've spent hours reading and trying things. The end-all-be-all of it is, "Are there paths of research you haven't tried yet?" Sources of research might be trying things in code, documentation, or blogs/tutorials. Try to run yourself out of options. Using the writing process to help you identify things to research is a good idea; just don't post it until you're done.

Comment: @MysteriousWhisper, just as jpmc26 said, it's not about the time, but rather about what options you have explored. Think of this: you are writing a question and in the back of your mind an idea forms that "maybe X works". You know doing X takes some time. Would you stop writing the question, go try X and come back if it also doesn't work? I would expect the answer to be "yes". In other words, if I ask you "have you thought about doing X", your answer shouldn't be "yes, but I was too lazy to try it". OP's question in particular shows this ("I thought of static, but didn't bother learning it")

Comment: That said, sometimes you simply cannot think of anything else to do. It's ok, that's when you ask a question. Obviously, the more knowledged you are in a field, the more options you can think of and therefore the longer it takes to finish your research.

Answer (score 15):

The only guidance I would throw at you for this one is that the down votes are likely to be social in nature rather than technical. Your question looks fine in my uneducated opinion. However that doesn't stop people with the power to vote from passing their judgement. Often people will also down vote because:

- they think your question is too simple (being a n00b doesn't count for these people)
- they think you should have done more research
- they think the question (or a close approximation) has been asked before on the site
- you've dared to ask a question in a tag that suffers from problematic low quality questions and those people have an itchy voting finger

A lot of times those reasons can be summarized down to *"Whaaaaa...??!!! Why would you bother our precious eyeballs with a question like **that**?"*. Your question could be perfectly reasonable and well constructed but that doesn't stop such people from throwing a quick down vote your way - especially since there is no penalty to down voting questions (it costs the voter zero rep).

Comment: I disagree with this answer. First of all, the question asks, "How could I have made the question better?" This offers no guidance on that. Second, it subtly suggests that the voters had no legitimate concerns with the question and voted frivolously, without any defense of why the question is good. The other answer does an excellent job of explaining what aspects of the question are *not* good, and provides a reasonable explanation for why it was downvoted. Even if you disagree with the reason, downvoters could certainly have held the same view presented there, meaning they did have a reason.

Comment: @jpmc26 I disagree with your disagreeance, I think you need to read it again. I stated the question looks fine to me, which means little or no improvement is needed. I've done my fair share of editing and reviewing over the years, so I've seen a lot of crap. Second, I wasn't being subtle - some tags do suffer from boorish behaviour.

Comment: @jpmc26 Third, the answer from Shahbaz is good, but we can all meticulously dismantle the questions of newer members. It's a fact of life that questions from new members are less than perfect, but this question was pretty good compared to some of the utter crap that comes through. Pointing out all the tiny imperfections that the OP was unaware of makes for a technically accurate answer (hindsight is always 20/20) but not necessarily helpful. You'll also notice I mentioned *they think you should have done more research*, which is exactly what Shahbaz elaborated on in depth.

Comment: @jpmc26 But thanks for your feedback, it's still welcome.

Comment: For what it's worth, I read and was in agreement with this answer before I wrote mine, and I did so only because my "comment" was too large to fit here.