# Why is the popular "How much research effort is expected" answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, meta, deleted-answers

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296) has been deleted as of yesterday. Similar to Jon Skeet's [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), this answer has been used by many users as a go-to link to comment when a question with no research or effort is asked.

> I'm removing this answer because it's not advice we want to give to new users -  Tim Post

IMO, this answer is applicable to everyone, especially new users. If the hyperbole is confusing, it could be edited out and it would still be a solid answer. I don't understand why it has to be deleted.

Here's a screenshot of the answer:

[image]

Comment: Wow, another relic of Stack Overflow bites the dust.

Comment: This is pretty bad. I've often linked to that answer in discussions (mostly to illustrate that people shouldn't say things like _googled a bit_ or _skimmed the docs_). Now all those links are dead, and refer to the second-best answer which has a different gist...

Comment: It could probably be worded a bit better but this is good advice in my opinion (and experience, I've learned much more from trying to avoid asking a question than I have from asking).

Comment: Also, I think that the people who upvoted the answer (or really, anyone) get that the point is not that you should go out, buy and read books before asking on SO. It's a hyperbole, and the point is you should put in the maximum amount of research effort that's feasible for you before asking. It explains that too: _The important point remains that we absolutely want you to do your homework. Understand that our time is not free, though we do not charge for it._

Comment: Er... the reason for deletion is quite clear. You may not agree with the reason, but asking "why was it deleted" seem rather disingenuous. I believe that what you want to ask is why is this answer not deemed suitable for new users.

Comment: To be honest, the _"anything to avoid posting another question"_, while not wrong, sounds a bit hyperbolic and passive aggressive. Again, it is not wrong and I agree with the answer. Would have preferred the answer to be edited than to be deleted, but Tim is paid to make these decisions. And deal with us. The content can be posted off-site and linked. Old links pointing to this answer are likely no longer relevant, since by now the users who got the link either picked up on the answer's advise, or didn't.

Comment: Reading the answer again, it mentions "try to avoid asking questions, but research first". This seems to be opposite to the present Stack Overflow goal of ["getting more new contributors"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386324/the-stack-overflow-i-wish-to-build-and-participate-in-is-no-longer-supported#comment705241_386324), and therefore deleted. This seems to be the most logical explanation.

Comment: Yeah - it's a relic from the days when SO was for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: It was a good answer, but a bit too facetious for it's own good. A rewrite to make it less over the top would have been preferable.

Comment: @Bhargav The answer kind of made the reader refrain from asking a question. Also for this, it could’ve been edited, deleting it was not a solution. Wonder how many people linked to this in comments and now the links are dead

Comment: @yivi Maybe it can be edited to remove the *"You never want to ask the question" or "horrible shame"* and other hyperbole to avoid any confusion (as many comments on the answer suggest). Otherwise, it's a solid answer. So, I don't understand deleting this extremely popular answer which is often used the go-to link by many users.

Comment: Again, I believe editing would have been preferred to deleting. But I also understand that drastic editing of that answer would also have brought meta-grief, probably accompanied by a bit or edit/rollback wars and post-locking. Deleting brings out meta-grief (this question), but it may last a bit less. A similar answer can be posted, taking the good from the deleted one and removing the hyperbolic parts.

Comment: @weegee yeah, I can agree with that too, but it was deleted by the director of Community Strategy for Stack Overflow, so I am trying to come up with some reason as to why he might have deleted it. (Also don't look at the diamond at the end of my name and think I'm some sort of official, I'm just a community mod. I'm as helpless as you are)

Comment: @weegee That the links are dead is a non-issue. Comments pointing to this kind of answer are supposed to be transient by nature. Also, links **are not dead**. They still point to the Q&A (the entire question and all its answers were not deleted), which is quite relevant.

Comment: @BhargavRao I know that you are a moderator and not a CM. Its just that this question needs to be upvoted more so that the answer can be undeleted and edited. That answer taught me very much thats why i just have 9 questions and 74 answers and im just 5 months new here

Comment: Imo editing this answer is not really feasible, if you strip out some of the hyperbolic parts (like the _shame_ stuff), the other parts gain strength because it becomes less obvious that it's hyperbolic, so you would need to totally rewrite it (and then it becomes a different answer). The only thing you could do is add a disclaimer, but it already has a short disclaimer.

Comment: I don't think the community has much a say in these things @weegee. Remember the 404 polyglot page? All the other Stack Exchange sites have their own different 404 page, but we don't, even though the meta asking for it reached 300+ upvotes. Or Remember the Facebook is tracking us post with 700 upvotes? Facebook is still tracking us. It all comes down to what the staff and the marketing team of Stack Overflow need.

Comment: @Bhargav that is so true but the most we can do is to upvote it. Better than nothing

Comment: IMO it is an excellent answer. I get there may be some language barriers at work but it is in no way unfriendly and running google translate would likely give you enough of a feel for what the overall message was. @ErikA's point about editing the hyperbole is a valid one.

Comment: Is the answer deleted because it hyberbolic sentence or because new user are not require to test their code anymore?

Comment: @xdtTransform It’s not like all the answers were deleted and there are no other answers that ask for more research and testing. Additional hyperbole doesn’t help.

Comment: I think this sums it up quite well: "This answer is toxic. Discouraging questions and requiring that one become a frustrated expert before shamefully seeking help is the most elitist, discouraging, and insecure thing you can tell a novice. The fact that this answer has so many up votes and was accepted makes me weep for the state of Stack Overflow. – KarlKFI Oct 13 '16 at 6:24" That was just Meta elitism but then a mod went ahead and made it a FAQ...

Comment: This is a middle finger to everyone who has ever tried to help curate content here. I regret the time I've wasted and wish I could revoke the license for the content I've contributed.

Comment: @Clive I'm going to stop helping completely, for good. No answers, no reviews, no votes, no flags - nothing. It's clear we're not wanted here, so what we can do is leave. Goodbye.

Comment: I don't know how to healthily express the amount of disappointment I have in this site right now.  That answer summed up just about everything you needed to know in order to start asking questions: "Get your stuff together before you post".  It didn't dance around and passively try to get a question wizard working for new users to ignore, it stated flat out, do your research and make as much **effort** (you know, the hover text on the voting arrows) as possible.

Comment: @yivi it matters when it breaks blog posts outside SO referencing this specific answer for one side or another about it. SO was usually cautious about talking on things before taking actions, the position has obviously been reversed and SO takes care only of SO now, breaking external links doesn't bother anymore.

Comment: @Tensibai Broken links in the open internet? Say it is not so! Any link can go stale. To any post here or to content elsewhere. There can be a lot of extremely valid reasons for not deleting this answer. Preserving hypothetical  links in the web is not one of them, IMO.

Comment: @yivi I'm just saying SO was used to open talk on meta _before_ taking this kind of action usually as **answers** on SO were deemed safe to link to after a few weeks, that's just a sign SO has radically changed in its behavior. With this kind of reasoning we should not close as dupe, as the dupe target may got deleted at any time without regards to the closed question not getting their answer anymore and just breaking the system at root...

Comment: I have to disagree with the majority. I like the answer. It's funny. And if new users get the joke then it will even help them. (Is it joking, sort of? I assume no one literally wants others to feel shame.) But what if they don't get the joke? The newer they are, the less likely they are to get it. Take the exact same message and repackage it. You can still include a little humor. Having thought about it, I can see why that answer, while sort of awesome, isn't the right message for new users.

Comment: I'm personally glad it's gone. That level of research effort has never been required. Ever. Some people wish that it was required, but it isn't. The most useful questions on Stack overflow tend to not show much in the way of research effort. The questions that have a wall of text listing every page theyvet viewed and why it doesn't answer their question tend to get ignored.

Comment: @TinyGiant "That level of research effort has never been required" but it's expected. It's expected that readers shouldn't duplicate efforts you already made. Showing that research is required.

Comment: @Braiam sure... Except that it absolutely is not and has never been, but sure.

Comment: @ScottHannen I think the majority actually wants the answer around. It was certainly well in the majority as far as votes go (it was removed unceremoniously by just one person with, from what we can see, no discussion on the matter). Personally, I would love to see anonymized data on the question success of the users who upvoted it vs downvoted (e.g. did most of the downvoters have bad question outcomes like closure/negative scores/etc.?) I know we'd never get such a thorough defense of such an action but hey... a guy can dream!

Comment: @TylerH - I get why the majority would want it. It's clever, funny, and sort of accurate if you get it. But it also addresses a key question of when people should use the site and what is expected. In this case, I'd argue that clear accuracy is more important than wit. Humor is weird. How many times do we think we're being funny but someone doesn't get it? I don't care that much and I don't overvalue my opinion. But in this case I think the majority is wrong for not looking past the humor and seeing how badly it could be misinterpreted.

Comment: @ScottHannen I think it's important to separate the signal from the noise there - it would be wrong to assume everyone who upvoted it didn't think there was absolutely no issue with how it was written. I agree that it was snarky, probably overly so, and definitely felt it could be better-written, but I still upvoted it because it was right and useful, even with the snark. I'd guess that a substantial portion of the other upvoters felt the same way.

Comment: @ScottHannen A lot of people here who opposed the deletion seem to agree that the answer was overly snarky, and could probably use a bit of a cleanup. People were upset because instead of editing it into shape, it was deleted, with absolutely no discussion or consultation of the community.

Comment: Also, it kept me from *documenting* stuff in selfie Q/A (because if I was able to find the answer *anywhere*, even if it's in some dusty book, decompiled source, some paywalled document, hardware manual or a gigantic string of convoluted, seemingly unrelated documents that in aggregate held an answer. With this as a standard pretty much nothing is suitable to post because *technically somebody* could have found that answer for themselves); not saying selfie Q/A is all fixed now but this helps the selfie Q/A situation a little tiny bit.

Comment: This answer is excellent advice to anyone wanting to improve their coding ability!

Comment: Oh come on, that answer wasn't anywhere near serious. It is a joke at best, mostly a rant, but not serious advice. You can't expect everyone to pick up the subtle irony and jokes, especially not when everyone isn't fluent in English. Sure it could be edited, by rewriting it in its entirety. But since there are already better answers, just delete it. No idea why everyone is getting so worked up over this.

Comment: I feel deeply sorry and concerned for a world in which the phrasing '... absolutely never do you want to click the "post your question" button' on a Q&A site is deemed too offensive, confusing, or unclear. Not being a native speaker of English does not automagically turn you into a mindless idiot. That's what I hope for at least while I shudder thinking of the 'quality' to be expected from people who'd actually be deterred by this answer ( the original one, not the version soaked in fabric-softener).

Comment: @collapsar I mean, personally I wouldn't get offended by somebody saying some content isn't a good fit for a site. IMO it wasn't confusing or unclear either. I read it as a very clear "if you find out something worth documenting, you need not post it on SO as a question", so... I didn't, and don't. I try and find a question that matches. It's not for me to decide on my own whether SO should or shouldn't host certain content, I'm just one user here. If I can't find a Q, I just keep that kind of stuff on internal company sites and personal notes. [Mission accomplished?](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: There's a gray area of content that's technically "out there somewhere" but you'd only find it with a lot of work, it's naturally harder to moderate and would require judgement calls from experts (maybe too hard to moderate and scale for this site, with its current toolset). SO is nowhere near a comprehensive repository of programming knowledge. A certain subset is very well covered (generally, code for popular web tech that can be copy/pasted). Venture out into the more "fringe" technologies and content and quality drops off fast. I'd rather have a low quality post than nothing at all.

Comment: This screenshot isn't special in any way - it mostly reflects the entire attitude of SO. I don't post questions because (as I commented on another meta post) there is no way to find some info regardless of how much research you do before you give up - the info is out there but it's not found and you didn't do enough research and your question won't be welcome even though if it were asked and answered, it would be a good question and future searchers would be able to find the info. By making questions unwelcome we lose good questions, finable answers and future visitors.

Comment: So, every question I have answered falls into the category where the information I gave came from somewhere and could have been found with enough searching.  I have seen comments where people advise that questions shouldn't be answered unless they have done "enough" research.  And since infinite research is impossible all questions fail on this point because any answer could have been found if just a bit more research had been done - some people devote their lives to researching a topic but that still isn't enough because the answer is still out there even if you don't find it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah sometimes you don't know the right words to search or you don't know every feature in your programming language. That's fine. This post is about questions with no effort. Questions where you google the title of the question with *site:stackoverflow.com* text to find the duplicate. Questions where users just copy paste their requirement / homework with zero effort. Questions where a simple debugging and checking the each value is enough to identify the issue.  We see hundreds of those questions everyday.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I'm kind of amazed that that answer made it this long. I'm absolutely *shocked* that it made it this long without any edits! For the top answer on a heavily-referenced meta question, that's rare... And in this case, unfortunate.

The core message is sound: search and research is essential, now more than ever. Even among our harshest critics, this is undisputed. We should do everything in our power to teach and encourage these skills!

However... The tone of the answer subverted that message. It was not written to be the general-purpose guide that it has been treated as. If our goal is to encourage folks to actually do that research, speaking to them like lazy children is counter-productive; if we want folks to aspire to be *better* we need to treat them like they can be.

Let's face it: the answer was more catharsis for frustrated teachers than a useful tool for learners. It reminds me more than anything of this famous XDA video...

That's funny stuff right there! Makes me smile every time. But even XDA doesn't blast that in the faces of their new users... They provide [an easy-to-read, calmly-written list of guidelines](https://forum.xda-developers.com/announcement.php?f=263), starting with...

> **Search before posting.**
>
> Use one of our search functions before posting or creating a new thread. Whether you have a question or just something new to share, it's very likely that someone has already asked that question or shared that news.

That's it. No hyperbole, no snark, no world-weary ranting. Just the facts and reasoning.

Let's do that too. [I've re-written that answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/261593/revisions), trying my best to preserve the message while ditching the nonsense. I think it's a clear improvement... How 'bout you?

Comment: Thanks.  It preserves the message and eliminates the snark.  Everyone wins at the cost of several additional gray hairs.

Comment: At this rate, I'll have torn out all my hair before it has a chance to turn grey, @Makoto. But for a good cause, I hope.

Comment: For that, you have to eat your hat first. After all, it's already part of your head.

Comment: I was in the middle of providing an answer here to highlight what parts of the answer were most getting misinterpreted/not understood, using the comments and such as evidence, because like you've noted, the message can be preserved without so much hyperbole that people who read it literally will think we really don't want questions. And when I refreshed and saw your edits, you made changes that were very similar to the ones I was going to suggest. Thanks for the effort you put into cleaning it up.

Comment: What do you expect people who don't agree that the asking should be the last step to do? Adding another answer or commenting does not seem to be an option. Is this the official stance now?

Comment: Ah... I didn't add that, @ErikA - got a few more people editing now. We might want to break out into a few different debugging posts if we wanna give folks specific advice like that.

Comment: "Even among our harshest critics, this is undisputed." I hate to have to point this out, but the deletion of this answer has resulted in quite a number of people disputing just that.  That research is essential  a *very* popular opinion, but it's not an undisputed one.

Comment: "Let's face it: the answer was more catharsis for frustrated teachers than a useful tool for learners." I'm not actually sure that's true.  I suspect it's the reason it got a lot of the upvotes it did, but my interpretation is that the author was speaking to *their own feelings*, not those they're trying to put onto others.  Many of the best programmers I know are proud of all of the problems they can solve, asking someone else to solve a problem they were capable of solving or finding an existing solution for *would be embarrassing*.  That's a motivator in trying to research their problems.

Comment: I'm very glad that the answer has been restored, even if it's with the tone shifted.  However, that doesn't really answer why the answer was **deleted outright instead of being edited**.  We have all this talk about trying to edit things into shape, but then we throw out the nuclear option on an answer that addresses the core values of the site and has at least 600 votes agreeing with it.

Comment: I hate to say it, @zero298 - but that's probably going to happen a lot more in the future. The company has been kinda checked out when it comes to Q&A for a long, long time - the classic absentee landlord situation. The folks here have been trying their best to keep things ticking along, but the support and coordination hasn't been there and it shows; now the landlord is trying to come back, clean the place up, fix the toilet that's been leaking, the roof that's been leaking, the HVAC with only two temperature settings: too hot and too cold... And there's gonna be a lot of dust and chaos.

Comment: Well, at least try talking with the tenants. It sucks when you are in the bath and the water just get cut off becase you are fixing the toilet. Or leaving a gaphole in the roof in the rainy season and not tell us.

Comment: I donno how much further I wanna go with that analogy really. But it does remind me of a time I visited a friend's apartment and found that the ceiling in the bathroom was only 5' high because a water leak had ballooned the paint so far as to require one to limbo under it in order to use the facilities... The whole while hoping it didn't pick that moment to collapse. I'm sure it was a real mess to fix, but fixing it was the right thing to do none the less.

Comment: Ironically it seems to be our milder critics who dispute that, @Servy. I don't think you can spend much time asking questions *or* trying to teach before you have to concede that learning how to research is the only way to get anywhere; it's the folks who aren't trying to learn *and* aren't trying to teach who seem to think that it's a one-sided problem. For everyone else, it's just debate over "ask first to get a direction on where to start reading" vs "ask last after reading everything".

Comment: You can edit the post yourself now, or kick off a separate discussion about that specific point, @ayhan. Or both.

Comment: @Shog9 I think the flawed assumption there is that people posting are always either trying to learn or teach.  Some people aren't looking to do either; they're just looking to, for example, have someone solve their programming problem.

Comment: Probably safe to say those folks aren't doing a lot of reading on meta either, @Servy. We've spent an awful lot of energy - going back almost to the launch of the site - optimizing guidance for the folks least likely to read it; just think about all the words that've been wasted on question-blocked users. We should maybe aim more for the folks who actually might care what we say.

Comment: @Shog9 You say they're not on meta and when when I say thing on meta like "people asking questions should be doing their research" I get pushback.  *On meta*.  So while it's often not regulars, the people both exist, and [occasionally] post on meta.  Now I'm not saying we need to cater to them (In fact I'm saying the opposite) but we *do* need to recognize that they exist.  Just pretending no one does that doesn't allow us to deal with them when they're here.

Comment: Oh, I know they exist, @Servy. I've replied to them too, and answered hundreds & hundreds of support emails from them... I can count the number of success stories on the fingers of one hand. Heck, I know that there are coding shops where their entire business model is built on hiring people to chop up a work order into small pieces, feed them through sites like SO, and then reassemble the results... Again, the chance that you're gonna convince someone to change that behavior with a bit of text is very close to nil. So why waste the effort? Write for the folks who'll listen.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not advocating convincing those people to not do things like that.  All I said was that the quote, "The core message is sound: search and research is essential, now more than ever. Even among our harshest critics, this is undisputed." isn't true.  There are people that dispute that.  And while we're not building the site for them, they will use the site, so the site needs to be designed around people like that using it.

Comment: This is what should've been done in the first place, in lieu of knee jerk deletion. Faith in SE restored (somewhat ;-).

Comment: Looks better, I retracted my (rather old) downvote on that post; at this point the only complaints I have about this aren't about new users or people who are looking to learn something, I'm more concerned about users that are trying to document stuff; the whole "end of your rope" thing still makes me think I shouldn't post selfie Q/A *because I found the answer*. It's true that I could try to search for a question that is *arguably, maybe related* but I'd find that kinda frustrating as somebody who hit the page from Google so I've held off on that

Comment: FWIW I would love to provide a replacement, on here or somewhere else, for some of the honestly terrible garbage (usually with a short lifespan) I had to sift through sometimes when I've been researching something. I leave documentation in my code or on internal sites, but I don't really know what to do with it other than that; I can't really start a blog, personal blogs tend to turn into 404 farms after a while anyway. Do you want quick tips and tricks or do you want journal papers? The latter doesn't happen very often.

Comment: I guess we now know [Cave Johnson probably spent too long on XDA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dt6iTwVIiMM)

Comment: _"Let's face it: the answer was more catharsis for frustrated teachers than a useful tool for learners."_ For the record, I distinctively remember reading the post around the time I started using SO, and it isn't nearly as insulting/unreadable/hyperbolic as you'd think. The post helped. A lot.

Comment: *We should maybe aim more for the folks who actually might care what we say.* - that train left the station about 5 years ago. The audience that actually might care what you say that remains **and** trusts you still; at this point is so small it is statistically insignificant.

Comment: *The core message is sound: search and research is essential, now more than ever.* this is **not** the core message of the original answer as it was worded. It was more along the lines of **learn your craft, put in some real effort to solve the problem yourself, find out if others had the same problem, and only when all else fails, come ask here because you will be able to ask a well described problem with all the details you will need to get the help you need and be understand the answers you get**. And honestly that is the *critical thinking* message our industry needs, not *search first*.

Comment: Oh geez, look at the edit history now! I wonder if the "system" will eventually stabilise haha.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I really wish the younger generations in the development world still thought like that.

Comment: Are you calling me old, @Gimby?

Comment: My 2c: The edit amounts to a substantial deterioration. The original conveyed the importance of the addressed issue to the community and the passion it may spark. Chances were high that a reader would remember the piece for it was not the standard well-measured wording to be found everywhere. People might even enjoy the humour of the text. None of that remains. I do understand the motive behind the edit but imho it is flawed: a deferential bow towards hypersensitive people who take themselves too seriously and the trope of rewards without effort.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  If you can spend more time looking for an answer, your question will be 10X better.  That's what a newbie will take away from that question.  If you don't have the fortitude to keep going because you saw that answer, maybe programming isn't for you.

Comment: Programming is an odd profession, @Jake, and a broad one... Easy to learn, impossible to master. Everyone is a rank amateur in some area, lacking even the most basic knowledge of terminology... While yet they may own some other area completely. Thus, thorough research is essential, yet not always productive.

Answer (score 38):

I think moderators or 20K users would better undelete this answer (possibly with some cosmetic edit, although provided screen shot doesn't seem to indicate strong need for that).

At other sites community doesn't hesitate to challenge and correct mistakes made by management ([example](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7649/31260)).

Comment: 20k users can’t undelete it (already tried). Mods only

Comment: @Clive thanks, I was wondering about this myself. Anyway, 10K/20K users can do mentioned cosmetic edit even while it still stays deleted (I'd consider removing part between "rope" and "that's", along with part of note explaining use of shame)

Comment: Yes, only mods can undelete mod-deleted-posts. Also applies for the "owner" of the post, they can't undelete that either.

Comment: OTOH it is now a part of FAQ. And the answer was at the top. As a guidance to newbie the now top answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261598/113662 fits much better.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec an edit with large warning saying this answer is hyperbolic and linking to the next one on top of it would have been enough. This kind of action is my opinion just trashing the SO community opinion in favor of commercial branding. This makes me feel unwelcome on SO anymore as SO the company (Tim is not an elected mod, but an employee) now single sided remove historical things without even opening a talk before because it doesn't match the company view.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec That answer "fits much better" only if your opinion matches that of the answerer. It is also filled with hyperbole and opinion: "Despite what the populace may lead you to believe" ... "Do not be intimidated into withholding questions simply because you don't hold a computer science degree in the subject, or are concerned about the precious minutes it would take away from Mother Theresa's busy schedule." How is that any more "welcoming" than the previously hyperbolic answer? Oh, it's less welcoming only to old users, not unwelcoming to new users. I see...

Comment: I would give them a bit more than 5 hours to defend their position before engaging in delete / undelete wars. If they don't, I guess it would be easy to test if they don't care much about the answer or our opinion. Though the fact this was just deleted without consulting us in advance says a lot.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Let's see how long that answer stands. The idea that "Stack Overflow's mission is to be an objective Q&A site _"for professional and enthusiast programmers"_" (quoted from the current top answer) also seems to run against the mission statement on the new homepage.

Comment: Sure @BaummitAugen, my comment was more directed at Tadeusz' thinking that answer was somehow less obnoxious than the previous top answer, than Stack Overflow's deletion of it anyway. SO can delete what they want when they want; it's their platform. There are risks involved in those actions, but they are well aware of them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Point taken. I edited the answer and removed those parts. You can see that Tim Post edited it yesterday too. Description of his edit is also quite interesting.

Comment: I think the main problem was the use of the faq tag. This isn't a faq.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec congrats for your edit on the answer still remaining. To repeat a bit, my problem is the action without warning. I may roughly understand the deletion, the problem seems to come from tagging the whole Q/A as faq where it shouldn't have been in first place.

Comment: Imo the problem likely was people slapping new users with this in an autocomment every time they thought someone didn't do their research.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec The issue with the new top answer is the same as the now-deleted one, except in the opposite direction. Where the deleted one went a little too far for the sake of emphasis (read: that's the purpose of hyperbole), the new top answer doesn't go far enough.

Comment: @ErikA Do you have any data to back that up or is it just a theory?

Comment: @TylerH Just a theory, I've seen quite a few autocomments that nearly made me empathize with the welcoming blogs and did refer to this specific post. I can only speculate about the true motivations behind deleting the post.

Comment: Now my edit got rolled back. I'm a bit upset. I raised a custom moderator flag on it.

Answer (score 14):

My gut reaction:  the answer is hyperbolic and laced with *just* enough sarcasm, that someone who simply glances at it without reading for context would be put off by it.

The answer *was* good, and I too don't like seeing it removed from after so long.  But given that we have people who [take "unwelcoming" to the levels of a rallying cry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386505/new-home-page-makes-it-seem-like-so-doesnt-allow-free-use-any-more?noredirect=1#comment706639_386505), its deletion was inevitable.

Answer (score 4):

Answers with that many upvotes should not be deleted offhandedly. Instead the community should be asked to improve them. Removing the apparent bad tone while keeping the content intact is quite easy to do. Everyone can help.

If we start deleting all the content on meta that we don't like, we will end with a very poor meta.

The answer has been un-deleted in the mean time but is still locked. To improve it, it needs to be unlocked. That should be done and then we can reformulate it improving the tone, but keeping the content intact.

Comment: Personally, I really don't like the style of the actions.

Comment: It was locked to give the CM community time to weigh in and ensure its content aligns with the company verbiage and code of conduct. It does no good for users to hear conflicting remarks. Once they say the present verbiage aligns wirh their messaging, it’ll be unlocked and rolled forward to the appropriate version. There was quite a bit of an edit war and lots of changes post @shog9 ‘s edit.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - A mod note under the post would have really helped prevent speculation about it. If the issue recently is transparency or lack thereof...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't really understand why you do so much work for them. If the company wants to keep the post locked, they should do it, not you. I think it should be unlocked and the community should have a try at improving it. The goal should be to keep the content intact but changing the tone, as said in this answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Done. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score -32):

This is my fault. I've been curating the FAQ and adding a lot of the proposed FAQ questions to the FAQ. When doing this I need to be cleaning up the answers and comments. The FAQ only needs one or two good answers. Unfortunately life off the site got in the way and I didn't complete what I began, but I am rectifying this.

Comment: Nope. While you might've played a role in this, this clearly wasn't your fault. You didn't make the decision to delete that answer.

Comment: This can't be _your_ fault, Yvette: the wiki answer could have been improved instead of being deleted.

Comment: I should have cleaned up all the posts before adding them to faq

Comment: So now all the *other* answers get deleted? This...thing grows messier by the second. But apparently that's how `faq` questions are supposed to be handled? If that amounts to basically *reshaping the entirety of the thread anyway*, I guess that could indeed have avoided some of this mess. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau this really is on me. ouchie wowser. Yeh I've deleted them and left comments for the authors to add salient points to the accepted answer. There's also been edits made to the accepted answer adding things from the others. There's no point having the same thing said over and over. Make one good answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw Shog9's extremely helpful edits. Though, they're largely orthogonal to the existence of other answers. But if that's how `faq`s work, whatever. But...after sudden removal of everything *but* that answer, this entire discussion feels about 567% more wasted now than it felt before (which was already quite a bit). But maybe it also encourages everyone to simply disengage from this mess.

Comment: "Make one good answer", now if we managed to get the main site to do the same.

Comment: Yvette, while I appreciate you trying to recognize your own hand in this, it really isn't your fault or your doing. That answer has been linked to since long before it was in the FAQ list, and the conflict surrounding it did not originate with your May 25th designation of it being an FAQ. Your action may have somewhat inflated the visibility of the conflict, but it was not the trigger instigating the conflict.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it is explicitly not your fault.  It's pretty clear from the edit history of the answer as to how the answer was deleted and your name doesn't match the delete action.

Comment: The part on cleaning up answers to create FAQ disturbs me. 'till now the guideline was "respect others' posts and work". Is it lifted in case of FAQ creation?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec it has nothing to do with respecting work, it's the nature of the `faq`. Please don't conflate the two. The faq is supposed to be a place for clear answers and a reference place for users. They are also always community wiki collaborations, meaning we don't need lots of answers under them

Comment: @YvetteColomb “*The faq is supposed to be a place for clear answers and a reference place for users.*” That’s fine for that FAQ, but where’s the relationship to that six year old Q&A that was never meant to be that specific FAQ? If you find that over 99% of that old Q&A doesn’t fit, wouldn’t be the logical conclusion, not to use that Q&A, instead of deleting most of it and editing the remains beyond all recognition? After all, you could have picked an arbitrary, entirely unrelated Q&A for that purpose and transform it into your desired FAQ with even less destruction (if it had less content)…

Comment: @Holger please be mindful before jumping to conclusions or making assumptions. Look at the edit history of the question. Mods do not decide what becomes a faq, they are tagged faq-proposal and when they mature and have enough votes, the mods add them to the faq. read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow

Comment: @YvetteColomb besides the fact that the post you have linked still is newer than the Q&A in question, it only describes a process of creating *new* Q&As as FAQ proposal. Which somehow makes sense, when you are going to interpret votes on the Q&A as votes for the faq-proposal. It does not make any sense to badge “faq-proposal” on a six year old Q&A and assume that everyone agrees with that proposal or, even worse, vandalizing the existing content and call that “they mature”, blaming the posts created years before the “faq-proposal” for not fitting into the faq shape.

Comment: @YvetteColomb and when you say “*Mods do not decide what becomes a faq*”, despite all these editing actions and deletions for turning the Q&A into an FAQ was made by moderators, who is then making the decision? That single user who added the `[faq-proposal]` badge to the question? Really?

Answer (score -70):

Why was it deleted? Perhaps because it gave *terrible* advice that has **long** been against site policy?

- It is a *long* time since the official policy was that [simple questions (which could be answered by reading a mountain of books. eventually) can be OK](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/22/are-some-questions-too-simple/).
- It is a *long* time since the official and community accepted policy was that [a question that can be answered by a simple Google can still be a valid question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions).
- The "answer" has no substance when stripped of its hyperbole.

But it was clumsy to delete it without an announcement or discussion.

Comment: "It is a long time since the official and community accepted policy was that a question that can be answered by a simple Google can still be a valid question." Are you sure you aren't conflating two things? That it can be found with a simple google search, isn't the same as no prior research done, which the answer mainly focus on.

Comment: Pretty sure [ask] has always started with "**Search, and research** 
...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest."

Comment: Seriously? Spend time hunting down resources that might contain your answer before you post a question is "terrible" advice? And you have the gall to complain about its hyperbole?

Answer (score -95):

The answer is simply over the top, and correcting that would mean writing a completely different answer. If you take all of the inside humor out of that answer, there isn't much left that *isn't* addressed by the now top answer.

It is just *too much* for someone not indoctrinated to the "cuddly snark" style (for lack of better phrasing), and off-putting enough in the absence of that to make new folks simply want to go elsewhere.

*Content sometimes gets deleted* when it falls out of relevancy. Our attrition rate, especially when it comes to the people we *don't* manage to entice to participate here on meta ***is disturbing*** and we've got to fix that if the site is going to be relevant to the expectations of people learning to code in 2019 as opposed to 2009.

Nowhere do we say research isn't expected, the top answer *specifically says it is*, we're just saying it without a lot of snark and hyperbole that's open to interpretation and *being interpeted* in a manner that's a lot different from the time that answer was written.

Comment: But the top answer *isn't* telling people to do their research.   It's telling people that they should be asking a question on SO even if the answers are already readily accessible.  It's telling people to *not* do their research, beyond just a simple search of SO.  If the answer was advocating for a similar research practices, but with simply a different tone, that would have been radically different.  "Do a search on SO", and "debug/troubleshoot the problem, search everywhere you can, many times, and search through every resource you can get your hands on" are not the same thing.

Comment: It's been a long week with a lot of stuff going on.  I see both sides of this argument in that yes, the amount of snark there is pretty significant, but then it raises a point about community culture.  I too am not particularly *thrilled* from its deletion, but I do wish that the circumstance had been a bit cleaner; that is to say, the emotions are still pretty raw over a lot of feeling like we're not getting listened to, and this only adds **more** fuel to that fire.

Comment: Step 1 and step 2 both say _research_. Go read the technical documentation. Go see if there's something already on the site about it. That's what we want people to do.

Comment: @Servy if the answer doesn't already exist on Stack overflow then further research is entirely irrelevant. There's no close reason for information existing somewhere else on the internet. If there was, the vast majority of Stack overflow content would be off-topic.

Comment: "Our attrition rate, especially when it comes to the people we don't manage to entice to participate here on meta is disturbing" Can I ask, why should we care? The perfect user for an Q&A is one that *doesn't post anything ever on the site*. They are the future readers, that saves time and resources by having a readily available answer to their question. Since you said once that you are a shareholder of SO Inc, is user growth actually included in the investor portfolio? That's only useful on social networks and SO Q&A isn't one.

Comment: @Braiam You should care because if new people don't start participating here there won't be any people here at all. When more people feel turned away than welcomed, something is wrong.

Comment: @TinyGiant You're free to reflect your own opinions of what research is expected in your own votes.  Other people reflected their opinions with theirs, and *overwhelmingly* indicated that they felt that the expected research for asking a question was not to just look on SO and nowhere else.

Comment: The current circumstances don't alter the fact that the answer is actively harmful and needs to go. We could be roasting marshmallows around a campfire and signing songs _and it would still need to go_.

Comment: @Servy Going to stop you there. Our surveys _overwhelmingly_ indicate that people don't want to make accounts and ask questions because they feel intimidated by bullish stuff _just like that answer_ and I can't believe the amount of effort people are putting into defending something _we all agree_ could be at least interpreted as hostile or over the top.

Comment: @TimPost An answer saying research on SO and an answer saying research *everywhere you can* are not the same.  The former is *completely inadequate* research in the eyes of *many* people, who reflected that opinion on that question.

Comment: @Servy A few hundred people on meta don't get to set all the rules for _tens of thousands of people_ who don't want to participate here, _mainly because of how abrasive this place can be_. You're arguing a consensus that exists plainly in your perception, and I can see why you'd defend that, but you're in an echo chamber that's _much_ smaller than you might realize.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa whoa hold on a second.  We don't get to set the rules for our own community?  Snark aside, what is the implication of this??

Comment: @TimPost SO managed to become extremely large and successful following the model that a highly curated site with high quality standards for questions and answers will produce useful content for lots of people.  *That* is what attracted your current, rather large, user base, and garnered the attention of the entire programming community.  Saying, "everyone will leave unless we remove our quality standards and encourage people who don't want to meet our current standards to contribute" just doesn't make sense to the rest of us.  We all came here for the high quality standards.

Comment: @TimPost We've seen what happens to all of the other sites out there that just let everything in, and say that it doesn't matter if you do your research, or ask clear questions, or are considerate of people answering.  Those sites *don't do well*.  Why is SO so dead set on turning itself into the sites it displaced?

Comment: @Makoto Exactly as [Jeff Atwood himself said it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386324/the-stack-overflow-i-wish-to-build-and-participate-in-is-no-longer-supported#comment706257_386324). In order to be "welcoming to new users", SE must be "unwelcoming to the experts/meta-crowd". It's easy to see why everyone is pissed.

Comment: @Makoto I said _all_ the rules. Ten people can't rule over thousands, and when the goals of a few are clearly not aligned with the needs of the majority, we have to step in. And again, I want to point out, _we agree the answer is overly-hyperbolic_. Also, the rules are what the UX ultimately enforces and .. we get to have a say in that too. You can't discount our needs to grow the community, especially when we see it constricting quickly, as major stakeholders here.

Comment: @TimPost I'm not arguing that people should be doing their research solely because of the votes on that question (although I would point out that FAQ posts are presented to a wide range of people, well beyond just meta regulars).  It's been a core tenant of the site's mission, official documentation, information *all over the place*, on meta and not.  This isn't some obscure bookkeeping rule that most users aren't even aware of.

Comment: @TimPost "You should care because if new people don't start participating here there won't be any people here at all." If the price is to get all the ones that are here out, I don't think that's a fair price to pay. I'm all for including them, but I'm not going to exclude others for that. The goal doesn't justify the means after all.

Comment: @TimPost Perhaps this would be an opportune time for you to explain what the _needs of the majority_ are, exactly, as SO sees them these days? A lot of people seem to be confused around that subject, myself included if I'm honest

Comment: Oh, btw, not unlike the Pareto principle, the minority produce most value for the majority of the users of the site. I think we shouldn't ignore how much added value each group add for SO.

Comment: Also, given that we're talking about the views of meta regulars vs. non-meta regulars, I feel obligated to point out that *the author of that post has posted exactly once on meta, and that was it*.  It wasn't posted by a meta regular (and personally, I'd argue that's *why* it's as over the top as it is, most meta regulars answering that question would have been more muted in their responses).

Comment: @TimPost:  Sure, we can't write all of the rules.  It should be collaborative.  We should all be interested in the same goals.  We shouldn't be at each others throats in this fashion.  But...the reality is that this is yet another thing that the veterans of the site see as a slight to the work they've built up, and it doesn't help things like morale or motivates the group of people to *support* the goals you're laying out here.  Anymore, this is just...depressing.

Comment: @TimPost Since you've finally admitted what a bunch of us have already been suspecting for a long time, I think it's probably better to come clean with this with an official blog post that details SE's direction, why it is doing it, and why it is worth alienating the entire meta community (which I do agree is an echo chamber). It's better to just give everyone the red pill now rather than to continue this endless frustration and lack of transparancy. This will go a long way to re-earning all of our respect.

Comment: @Mysticial Sara Chipps is working on a blog post for just that. We haven't been avoiding it or not wanting to say certain things, in fact I think the problem is having these conversations in _too_ many places and it just gets fragmented and ordered incorrectly as people try to parse it. That's .. a major motivation for moving primary communication back to the blog, while encouraging any follow ups to be asked individually on whatever meta someone wants to use.

Comment: @TimPost When you get time, could you elaborate on that 'constricting quickly' bit? I probably would have missed any blog post talking about it, but this is the first I've heard of large-scale declines in important stats (pageviews, I'd guess?)

Comment: @Undo Not pageviews, and not really a single thing to point at. It's the sum of a lot of stuff not happening. It boils down to not enough people investing in curating a presence on the site, at all (whether it's asking, answering, just editing and voting, updating profiles, etc). And when you pair this with what we're seeing from our surveys, it's saying we have a lot of work to do (and I'll freely admit 1/2 of that is in UX problems and inadequate tooling). But we can't ignore the other half which is perception and experience.

Comment: If anything, imo the whole thread has to go. Leaving the top answer with _only research on Stack Overflow, Googling is not required_ gives a wrong representation of community consensus on the subject. Deleting the top answer but leaving the rest severely misrepresents voting and consensus. I'm sure if that answer wasn't there, a different answer requiring more research would've been posted and top voted.

Comment: I'll wait for the blog post, but all I'll say is that if curation isn't seen as something integral to this whole process, then it'll turn into a *whole* hot mess.

Comment: It's baffling what a hard time people have with actually grasping what the remaining top-voted answer (now again second highest after undeletion of the controversial one) is saying. People seem to be entirely overreading the first point that's about documentation and tutorials, which *is* practically Googling, and think all it says is "search SO". A reading that seems...entirely oblivious at best (and at worst, well...).

Comment: @ChristianRau Nope. Reading the docs and following the tutorial is not at all research into one specific problem. Ever tried figuring out _why does this specific program have a memory leak_ by reading general documentation or following a general tutorial? For debugging problems, that answer doesn't seem to apply at all. In the comments, the author of that answer is explicit that he sees SO as separate from Google and wants every little problem to be discussed on SO as well, a sentiment that I certainly don't share.

Comment: And you Google during your debug sessions? (Well, I do, too, but only when the debug run is slow.) ;-)

Comment: @Makoto It's not going to be an easy blog post to write. Red pill means red pill. Anything that properly gets the message across is going to upset and drive away a large portion of the community. The fact is that SO has changed. It is no longer what many people want it to be. Those who have been around and don't like the new SO are probably going to leave. The way I see is that is that a lot of us are zombies leftover from the "old" SO that have no place in the "new" SO. So kill us now and put us out of our misery.

Comment: Eh, I google a lot during my debugging sessions, and find out a lot about weird undocumented behavior of the host application/framework I program with. That's how I solve most of my problems. Wouldn't be able to program effectively without it.

Comment: @Mysticial:  Yeah, I think I'm largely okay with that at this point.

Comment: Apparently "documentation and tutorials" seems to be understood as something way more specific than "the wealth of information the internet has to offer". I guess that's where people keep interpreting it differently.

Comment: @ChristianRau _Seems to be understood_ because it's stated that way in the comments. The author there is rather explicit about it.

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for no comments. I see an answer advocating research and I agree with it. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau Did you just not notice the bolded part of the answer where it says that it doesn't matter whether the information exists everywhere else on the internet, that as long as it's not on SO, it should be asked on SO?  Or did you just stop reading after the first sentence where it suggested an action it later walked back.  No reading of comments needed.

Comment: @ChristianRau It even uses deliberately inflammatory and insulting language to say that you should have no concern for the time of people answering your question, even if it is in fact readily accessible elsewhere, that you should be asking it anyway.

Comment: @Servy No, I noticed that. But...it's also largely orthogonal to the considerations about research effort (since the implication is that this *hasn't* been found in the asker's genuine research). Afterall about *every* answer posted here exists in some form on the internet (yes, even to the good well-researched questions). That's the entire nature of SO, condesning information into Q&A form. Hardly *anyone* on SO is ever expressing genuinely original ideas.

Comment: @ChristianRau No, that's not true.  SO does in fact do more than just regurgitate information that's readily accessible elsewhere.  There are in fact people asking questions not solved by looking elsewhere, where SO is actually adding value to the programming community by expanding the information available to future programmers who *do* do research on that problem.  *That* is the entire nature of SO.  SO was not designed to be a scraping site trying to generate ad revenue by posting others' content.

Comment: @Servy And that language was removed largely. (Granted, it was since reinstated, as was the answer from this meta discussion, so whatever.)

Comment: @Servy - Insulting is subjective. Otherwise everyone would be insulted by the same thing. I am not insulted. Answering questions doesn't take away from anyone's time, ever. We give our time. Or we don't. If answering questions doesn't take away from anyone's time, why should users be concerned that it will?

Comment: *if the site is going to be relevant to the expectations of people learning to code in 2019 as opposed to 2009*, you are not catering to *people learning to code in 2019* you are catering to people that just want their work done for them in 2019 that just happen to have to use *code* to get that work done. There is no *learning* being done, not by even the loosest definition of the word based on an objective review of the fresh *give me teh codez* "questions" posted front page every hour. The current charter admits as much otherwise it would have never been changed from the *quality* charter.

Comment: @ScottHannen Because entitlement is only bad in *one* direction and we wouldn't want all the valuable experts to feel treated like...new users. ;-)

Comment: @TimPost , regarding "constricting quickly". When you see that "not enough people investing in curating a presence on the site", could it be because the site has been catering to "give me the coodez" crowd for that last 5 years, and these people are not, by and large, the kind of people who "curate a presence". Could it be that your "welcoming" policies are catching up with you now?

Comment: I wonder how hard it was to leave a comment for the author to edit the answer. I mean, isn't Jon Skeet kind of a celebrity here? After all, Shog9 had to step in and correct this mistake which you (Tim) claim that's not possible

Comment: One thing I'd say.... "We have surveys and other datapoints proving this is a problem and needs fixing"... Can... Can we see said datapoints? You're going off *more information than us*, there **will** be a disconnect. Maybe if we saw all you did, we wouldn't have the disconnect. In an ideal world, we wouldn't need for that, as the community would trust SO.... that's unfortunately not where we are anymore :/

Comment: I take real issue with a lot of the things happening here. First and foremost, while I may be OK with the outcome of that answer being deleted, it's hard to be sure, because what I *am* sure of is I'm **not OK** with *how* it was deleted, e.g. unilaterally, without any discussion or attempt at editing it. Did you just wake up today and say "I feel like deleting that answer. Yep, today's the day."? Or was there some internal discussion; some raging debate among employees? Was there something raised by internal tools like surveys *recently that prompted this action*? Who knows! You haven't said.

Comment: Second, "content sometimes gets deleted when it falls out of relevancy" OK, but this was not irrelevant, nor was it deleted for matters of relevancy--you said so yourself. You deleted it because "it needed to go". Irrelevant content should probably be cleaned up, but it's not a matter of any urgency. And if it's a matter of wrong content, you are the Director of Community Strategy at Stack Overflow. Meta Stack Overflow *is your community*, so engage with your community on fixing what you think is the problem. Be clear about the issues you've identified and suggest fixes or ask for suggestions.

Comment: Third, and perhaps most importantly, "*A few hundred people on meta don't get to set all the rules for tens of thousands of people who don't want to participate here, mainly because of how abrasive this place can be.*" and "* I said all the rules. Ten people can't rule over thousands, and when the goals of a few are clearly not aligned with the needs of the majority, we have to step in.*" the obvious inaccuracy of the statements aside, aren't you being hypocritical when you are overruling the majority here (Meta consensus of several hundred people) with your unilateral deletion of the answer?

Comment: I'm not nearly as avid a participant on Meta of other sites as I am here, but... I have always had the distinct impression that on all of those other sites, the Meta community got to decide what content they accepted and what they wanted the rules to be. Yes, Stack Overflow is *freaking huge* in comparison, but... do those rules just not apply to us? Does Meta Stack Overflow have no actual say in determining the policies that apply to Stack Overflow? If not, why should any of us bother participating here? Or in curating the content on the main site?

Comment: @ScottHannen When I called it insulting it's because it seems that the *intent* of comments like, "concerned about the precious minutes it would take away from Mother Theresa's busy schedule" was that the *intent* of those statements was to be insulting, not that I was insulted by the very idea that people are not expected to do research (I will admit I do find statements like those upsetting, but I would not at all claim everyone who makes such a statement is being insulting; the problem is that the *way* that that person made those claims was intended to insult people with an opposing view).

Comment: The analogy I feel compelled to make is that we're trying to cultivate an environment that encourages *teaching people to fish* here, and you keep slapping our wrists and saying "no, just give them a darn fish and send them off", instead. But the frustrating thing is every time we ask "what are we doing wrong?" you come out and say "we agree you should teach people how to fish, but you should be nicer (or whatever attribute) in doing so", meanwhile your actions don't match up; you are still slapping wrists and handing out fish.

Comment: On an unrelated note, regarding "*moving primary communication back to the blog*", if you are sincere about doing that, you should turn off comment moderation there. It's impossible to interact in any meaningful way with a blog post if I have to wait 3 days to know whether my comment got approved.

Comment: @Servy Regarding "Why is SO so dead set on turning itself into the sites it displaced?" my guess is because of debt. They owe a lot of their growth and board seats to VCs and angel investors, and Silicon Valley / startup culture in general is well known for having an incredibly unhealthy obsession with constant growth. Instead of reaching a healthy size and then continuing to tend the herd you have, they push for growth because, well, a bigger profit margin and market cap will make any VC's eyes light up. So the marching orders become something like "grow. whatever it takes."

Comment: @TylerH While that's possible, it's worth noting that SO didn't take on any VC money until after it was quite large already, so we were told they were able to get favorable terms with the VCs as a result.  Additionally, we were told at the time that this allowed them to pick investors that were on board with the site's model of existing, and plans for growth.  So either the SO staff didn't do a good job of picking good investors (despite a very favorable bargaining position) or something has changed. Maybe the investors sold their share? Who knows.  But this isn't a typical investor situation.

Comment: @Servy would you happen to have a link to where they discuss their VC situation?

Comment: @DavisBroda [This](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2010/02/14/raising-money-for-stackoverflow/) is the basis for most of my statements.  Posted by the co-founder and, at the time of posting of that post, CEO of the company.

Comment: @Servy Or SO staff's plans for growth were unhealthy from the outset.

Comment: @TylerH I refer you to the exact same link, which both briefly describes plans for growth, and links to additional posts that go into more detail on the topic.

Comment: @Servy I've read it before (though it's been a while), but the takeaway there is yes, the growth goals are unhealthy, such as they are briefly alluded to in the blog post.

Comment: @TylerH Most of the growth goals were in the non-SO sites.  Basically, the goals were around making Q/A sites on other topics as successful as SO was for programming, which doesn't appear to have happened on as many topics as I suspect the company would have wanted.  It would make sense that they'd therefore consider making changes to some of the smaller sites to try to figure out how to make them more successful in their corresponding domains.  It doesn't explain (to me) why it would motivate trying to squeeze the golden goose in order to get an egg a bit sooner at the expense of its health.

Comment: Your attrition rate is getting *really* bad when it comes to veteran users whom you've apparently made it your mission to alienate. That's a lot worse, because we have rather a lot to do with making this site what it is and in driving new users to it. You might want to take a step back and reconsider before you engage the nuclear weapons. Meta has always been a platform for people to share their opinions in a constructive way, and although you might disagree with it, that answer was neither rude nor inappropriate. Wrong answers can be downvoted, not deleted. That's always been the rule, Tim.

Comment: Please do let me know if the rules have changed, by the way, so I can be sure to delete this answer as being over the top and uncorrectable without a major edit.

Comment: similar thoughts as what @Arkadiy writes go through my mind on reading this. If this is so - "not enough people investing in curating a presence on the site" - then alienating those who actually perform this work so that they stop or leave, and apparently not supporting policies that would *reduce* the curation required seems rather contradictory. Note that this comment has nothing to do with the deleted answer / FAQ that originated this discussion. I landed here starting from the topic about "Why are you still here", which I, too, have been asking myself (and I hope you're reading).

Comment: @TimPost "A few hundred people on meta don't get to set all the rules for tens of thousands of people who don't want to participate here, mainly because of how abrasive this place can be." That [isn't the reason people avoid participating here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362532/1394393) They might give that excuse, but the reality is they just don't want to put the time and effort into creating good content. The fact we get so many poorly conceived and poorly presented questions every single day is proof enough. You are letting your judgement be clouded by social justice prejudices.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for undeleting all the answers on that question. It gives a certain perspective as to how people think and what each person expects out of the asker, and the viewpoint of each user.

Comment: @jpmc26 It’s definitely the reason *I* avoid participating: Meta is toxic. I hope my stats on the main site make it obvious that I *am* willing to put in the time and effort. Just not here. But I also disagree with Tim: Obviously a minority of people will *always* make the rules for the vast majority, and at the moment it’s a much smaller  minority (= Stack Exchange employees) than the Meta minority.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was talking about the main site, but as for Meta, it is by design a place for differing ideas to clash. There is inherently some level of conflict in airing such disagreements and trying to find a path forward; that's unavoidable. Furthermore, Meta necessarily requires advocating the site's values to discuss the reasons for any course of action. That means you're going to have to have a bit of thick skin and some dedication to engage in the kinds of discussions Meta was designed for, but that isn't the same thing as toxic.

Comment: @TimPost "A few hundred people on meta don't get to set all the rules for tens of thousands of people who don't want to participate here, mainly because of how abrasive this place can be." If you meant this statement to say that Meta doesn't get to say anything about our community norms and policies, then I submit to you that you have denied the main purpose for which Meta was created. If you don't want Meta to influence site policy anymore, then SO will have to take over its role directly and ordinary users should not longer be allowed to post answers on Meta.

Comment: @jpmc26 What you’re describing isn’t the same as “toxic”, and does not inexorably lead to toxicity. I realise that many people don’t understand this, which is itself part of the problem.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Then I do not understand to what you're referring because what I described is what I see generally happening on Meta.